# Correct location of initramfs.cpio file when compiling kernel

Tags: kernel, initramfs

I am following [this article](http://www.aclevername.com/articles/linux-xilinx-tutorial/minimalist-initramfs.html) and generated an `initramfs.cpio` file.

Now the tutorial mentions that I have to put this file in build directory:

```
Finally, you have to rebuild the kernel again:

# 0. Copy the CPIO archive to your kernel build directory:
cp initramfs.cpio .
```

But I dont see any build directory:

```
[root@xilinx linux-xlnx]# ls 
arch     CREDITS        drivers   include  Kbuild   lib          mm              README          scripts   System.map  virt
block    crypto         firmware  init     Kconfig  MAINTAINERS  Module.symvers  REPORTING-BUGS  security  tools       vmlinux
COPYING  Documentation  fs        ipc      kernel   Makefile     net             samples         sound     usr         vmlinux.o
```

What is the correct place then?

my board is xilinx Zynq based on ARM

Answer (score 0):

In the context, kernel build directory doesn't mean the directory named `build` in kernel source tree, but rather the directory which holds the sources and where the build is happening. So you want to copy your initramfs to your `linux-xlnx` directory.